# create ICMP packets in macOS with the DF flag on

Tags: c, macos, networking

I've tried to modify the [SimplePing](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/SimplePing/) example in Apple website to send ICMP packets with DF flags on (I'd like to implement my own version of path mtu discovery)

I did so by using setsockopt with the correct attribute, right after socket was created :

```
fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_ICMP);

int val = 1;
setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_DONTFRAG, &val, sizeof(val));
```

However, Although the operation return success(0), from wireshark I could clearly see that the icmp packet had the DF bit unset ... Please help me figure out what's wrong in my code. are there other alternative to do it ?

Thanks !

Comment: Did that `setsockopt()` call return success?

Comment: You can implement PMTUD sending any protocol. You just need to receive ICMP errors for a packet too big, but you do not need to send as ICMP. Really, you should just build it into your application to react to the errors by reducing the data size. You do not need a separate tool.

Comment: @RonMaupin, my client is communicating to a server that I don't have control over, so I cannot invent new protocol for that... under this limitation, perhaps you can suggest a way to detect fragmentations ? I only know that icmp return code=fragmentationNeeded , perhaps you can show me another approach ?

Comment: You are not inventing a new protocol. The proper way to do PMTUD is to respond to ICMP too big errors by reducing what you send. Trying to do it with a different protocol can give you incorrect results (may take a different path than your application data). Your application should be listening for and responding to other ICMP errors, anyway. The server that you do not control plays no part in this.